# What will the best strategy to match overlapping date and time of two persons timings in no SQL database

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

What will the best strategy to match date and time of two persons timings. Like one person is free from

> 15th june 2015 9:00 to 05: PM
>
> 16th june 2015 10:00 to 06: PM
>
> 17th june 2015 9:00 to 05: PM

and second person free timings are

> 15th june 2015 8:00 to 04:00 PM
>
> 16th june 2015 10:00 to 06:00 PM
>
> 17th june 2015 9:00 to 02:00 PM

how to save them in jdo at google app engine datastore so that it will take less time and read operations to query. currently i am using a method which is taking approx 1,500 read operations for one query. please help.

my jdo structure is

```
private String id;
private String name;
private userKey; (Foreign key from user table.)
private String designation;
private Set<Long> timing; // it has timing for 15 min interval [201506150800, 201506150815, 201506150830...]
```

while query i have to find which employee has overlapping timing with my timing. Like i am free from 7:00 9:00 on 15th June 2015 so i can book appointment with one of them.

Comment: define what operations you will perform on the data? i.e what do you need to display? You could have a class being the availability, with startDate, endDate and userName for example ... and do a query of all people available at a particular date+time.

Comment: Hi Neil i have update my question. Is it more clear for you now?

Comment: please give some format to your posts to make it a bit more clear so users can help you better

Comment: @Hrishabh your question could be answered about two dozen ways... from a BigQuery job to do it, to saving timeslots and keeping track on who's free, to having parents and childs... you'll need to be a lot more specific as to your requirements, model, etc. Plus you say you currently have a method, what is it? show your current work, show what you tried to do to improve the behavior :)